# Are the death threats against Trump electors unprecedented in America?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, electoral-college, crime

[Detroit News](http://www.detroitnews.com/story/news/politics/2016/11/17/elector-threats/94003176/) reports:

> Trump’s opponents have deluged [Michael] Banerian and other GOP electors with pleas and nasty emails to reverse course and cast their ballots for Clinton, according to the Michigan Republican Party.
>
> “You have people saying ‘you’re a hateful bigot, I hope you die,’” he said.
>
> “I’ve had people talk about shoving a gun in my mouth and blowing my brains out. And I’ve received dozens and dozens of those emails. Even the non-threatening-my-life emails are very aggressive.”
>
> The Detroit News verified one message containing a death wish and another containing a death threat, in which the person told Banerian he would “put a bullet” in his mouth. Banerian said he deleted the rest of the emails and messages “because as you can imagine they’re clogging up my email.”

The same thing is happening to electors in other states.  [NBC](http://www.nbcdfw.com/news/local/Texas-Elector-Says-Democrats-Trying-to-Sway-His-Vote--401818136.html) Dallas-Fort Worth affiliate reports:

> In Texas, unlike some other states, electors may change their mind, and it has Democrats from around the country urging them to do just that, said Alex Kim, an elector for Texas’ 24th Congressional District.
>
> “At first everyone was kinda enchanted by it,” Kim said. “Now all the electors are starting to get beaten down. There are some electors who have been threatened with harm or with death.”

Is this form of Elector intimidation new to this election cycle?  Have there been recorded instances of threats to other Electors in the past?

Comment: It seems the issue of electoral voting system comes around during elections. This question seems more like a 'rant' than an actual question. Be more specific about your question. Are you wanting only faithless electors that were threatened?

Comment: Are you asking if casual death threats on social media is unprecedented?

Comment: @blip. No. These weren't on social media. I'm specifically asking have there been previous threats to electors in order to change their vote

Comment: The reader is left wondering if the threats were attributed overheated hyperbole, anonymous credible threats, bad pranks, the work of trollish [agents provocateurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_provocateur), or any of the various permutations of those.  If possible, please clarify whether or not some or all of these threats were anonymous; if the reports quoted didn't include that information, please specify the fact that the reports _didn't_ say.

Comment: Emails are never truly anonymous

Comment: @Killer066  There are no faithless electors yet.  Until December 19th, electors can't be faithless.  They haven't voted and thus haven't broken faith.  Also, I think that this is aimed at creating faithless electors, not preventing them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partisan lobbying and even threats, both for and against "faithless" electors, are not unprecedented.  [Robert M. Alexander](http://www.onu.edu/arts_sciences/history_politics_justice/faculty/robert_alexander), (in a 2012 CNN op-ed piece advocating in favor of the [Faithful Presidential Electors Act](http://www.uniformlaws.org/Act.aspx?title=Faithful%20Presidential%20Electors%20Act)), wrote....

> In 2004, I published a study aimed at shedding light on the mysterious
>   figures who serve as presidential electors. In the hotly contested
>   2000 election, many electors were subjected to vigilant lobbying
>   campaigns. Some received thousands of e-mails; at least one received a
>   death threat.
>
> -[Rogue electors threaten elections' integrity](http://edition.cnn.com/2012/10/22/opinion/alexander-electors/)

Comment: It seems as though the proposed 2010 *Faithful Presidential Electors Act* would have had the same effect as abolishing the office of Elector, (since if enacted, electors would *never* do anything), while retaining the electoral vote per state ratio.   It would have been a state-centered political end-run around the need for a federal constitutional amendment.

Comment: It's interesting that to date that pressure is being applied asymmetrically